# When I add an aggregate function to a query with no results, I get an empty row

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

When I add an aggregate function to the SQL query, I get a row of empty values returned. If I take the aggregate function out, I get no rows returned.  Why is this?  If there is nothing to return, I don't want a row.  In my schema, each envelope can have many transactions.  Here is an example of what I'm seeing:

```
sqlite> SELECT envelopes.*, SUM(transactions.amount) FROM envelopes LEFT OUTER JOIN transactions ON transactions.envelope_id = envelopes.id WHERE envelopes.user_id = 1;
id          name        user_id     income      unassigned  parent_envelope_id  expense     created_at  updated_at  SUM(transactions.amount)
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ------------------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ------------------------

sqlite> SELECT envelopes.* FROM envelopes LEFT OUTER JOIN transactions ON transactions.envelope_id = envelopes.id WHERE envelopes.user_id = 1;
sqlite> select sqlite_version();
sqlite_version()
----------------
3.7.5           
sqlite>
```

I would love to know how to use the SUM() function and still get no row returned when there is no information.  I tried grouping by all the columns in the envelopes table and that seemed to fix it, but I'd rather not group if I don't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to group on every column. You just need to group on `envelopes.ID` and then join to get the remaining columns. Try this query instead:

```
SELECT
    envelopes.id,
    envelopes.col2,
    ...
    envelopes.coln,
    totals.total
FROM envelopes
JOIN
(
    SELECT envelopes.id, SUM(transactions.amount) AS total
    FROM envelopes
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transactions
    ON transactions.envelope_id = envelopes.id
    WHERE envelopes.user_id = 1
    GROUP BY envelopes.id
) AS totals
ON totals.id = envelopes.id
```

Answer (score -1):

To use aggregate function SUM, further you should use 'GROUP BY'.
read sql manual, i.e. http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlsum.php